# Search records in SQL Server using CASE based on one Input Parameter in Where clause

Tags: sql-server, search, case

I have a situation in where I need to search for records in as SQL Server table based on a Column.

I have a table in which I have records as in the image uploaded.

Based upon the Status selected I need to structure my Stored Procedure with CASE to search for the selected records.

[Click to see the issue Image](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img812/1222/surb.jpg)

The Status field stores only 2 types of values **"Pending"** or **"Complete"** not **"OverDue"** , OverDue is when **Status='Pending' and EndDate < getdate()**.

Now I to search tasks based on their status selected, and If I select status as **"OverDue"** it should show me only the first 2 records.

How can I use CASE or any other alternative to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view

```
CREATE VIEW your_view
  AS
SELECT id
     , taskname
     , startdate
     , enddate
     , CASE WHEN status = 'Pending' AND enddate < Current_Timestamp THEN
         'OverDue'
       ELSE
         status
       END As status
FROM   your_table
```

Then you can select from it directly

```
SELECT id
     , taskname
     , startdate
     , enddate
     , status
FROM   your_view
WHERE  status = 'OverDue'
```

Alternative approaches:

```
DECLARE @search varchar(10) = 'OverDue';

-- Alternative option 1
SELECT id
     , taskname
     , startdate
     , enddate
     , status
FROM   your_view
WHERE  CASE WHEN status = 'Pending' AND enddate < Current_Timestamp THEN
         'OverDue'
       ELSE
         status
       END = @search

-- Alternative option 2
IF @search = 'OverDue'
  BEGIN
    SELECT id
         , taskname
         , startdate
         , enddate
         , 'OverDue' As status
    FROM   your_table
    WHERE  status = 'Pending'
    AND    enddate < Current_Timestamp
  END
ELSE
  BEGIN
    SELECT id
         , taskname
         , startdate
         , enddate
         , status
    FROM   your_table
    WHERE  status = @search
  END
```

Comment: hello gvee..Thank you for your reply ,Both are helpful.

It worked with View also , but I cannot use it in my SP since I have a lot of input parameters to check which is not allowed to add Parameters in View.

Comment: And I am working my way along with the second option you provided.
Thank You Again !!

Comment: Second solution worked out fine for me !! 
Thanks :)